# jQuery - Style If Variables Match Within Element

Tags: jquery, variables, if-statement

How do I apply a style to a div **only if** two variables match within that div?

I believe I'm incorrectly using the jQuery `.each()` method.

My goal is to apply a color change only to the first `div.main` based on matching text of two elements. Variables `a` and `b` match within the first `div.main`. Those variables don't match in the second `div.main`.

But rather than a color change to the first `div.main`, I'm getting "`no matches exist`."

**I'm not asking how to simply assign a style to a div. I'm asking how to style a div only if the text of two elements within the div match.**

Thank you in advance for the help!

https://jsfiddle.net/md32/ue1t3pov/35/

```
<div class="main">
    <a>
        <span>make this red</span>
    </a>
    <div class="section">
        <div></div>
        <ul>
            <li>make this red</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="main">
    <a>
        <span>don't make this red</span>
    </a>
    <div class="section">
        <div></div>
        <ul>
            <li>again, don't make this red</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

```
var a = $('div.main a span').text();
var b = $('div.section ul li').text();

$('div.main').each(function() { // for each 'div.main'
    if (a === b) { // if these two variables match
        $(this).css('color','red'); // color 'div.main' red
    } else {
        alert('no matches exist');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to me, it looks like you are having a logical issue. You are declaring a and b directly before you start your each loop.

You are imagining that the values of a and b are changing inside of your loop. but they are not.

I would recommend putting in a print statement so that you can see what the values of A & B are during your loop.
(**this code prints out to show you your error**)

```
var a = $('div.main a span').text();
var b = $('div.section ul li').text();

$('div.main').each(function() { // for each 'div.main'
alert("a is -> "+a+"\n b is -> "+b+"\n");

if (a === b) { // if these two variables match
    $(this).css('color','red'); // color 'div.main' red
} else {
    alert('no matches exist');
}
});
```

Here is an example of dynamically assigning a and b so that you get more of what you expected ( and also note the use of first(). If you run the above code first and see you were returning more than you expected with your selectors. (**this code does what you want it to do**)

```
var a;
var b;

$('div.main').each(function() { // for each 'div.main'

a = $(this).find("a span").first().text();
b = $(this).find(".section ul li").first().text();
console.log(a);
if (a === b) { // if these two variables match
   $(this).css('color','red');

} else {
    alert('no matches exist');
}
});
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you for going into detail on where I went wrong, and then providing a solution. This helps a lot.

Comment: Glad to help! Hope it was instructive. One of the ways I have really learned a lot is by using print statements to debug my code. Its always nice to see what you are actually getting.

Comment: I will remember that. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

the error is because you are not comparing the correct data. I changed up the javascript code so that it compares the correct elements and I changed the condition for printing out that there are no matches. The no matches would print if any of the divs did not have a match.

```
var counter = 0 ;

$('div.main').each(function() { // for each 'div.main'

    if ($(this).find('span').first().text() === $(this).find('li').first().text()) { // if these two variables match
        $(this).css('color','red'); // color 'div.main' red
        counter = 1;
    } else {
        if(counter === 0) {
       alert('no matches exist');
       }
    }
});
```

Additionally if you wanted to count the number of divs that have matches you could change the counter value assign to this:

```
counter = counter  + 1;
```

Comment: I'd upvote this, but my rep is too low. When you say I'm not comparing the correct data, are you saying I cannot compare variables within an .each() function like I have, or are you saying I'm not iterating through the html correctly... or are you saying both? Haha.

Comment: Glad I was able to help, you should mark it as the answer so that it helps others know that this question was answered: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers